# passing radio button value to sql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have four radio button cold,warm,active,all.It display as button.If I click cold button value 'cold' is passed to the query and vice versa.Based on the radio button The query get changed.
[image]

I want to show either cold or warm or active mode of records so I use radio button.

**HTML**

```
   <input type="radio" name="sta_choice" id="o1" value="Cold" onclick="handleClick(this.val);"><span>Cold</span>
   <input type="radio" name="sta_choice" id="o2" value="Warm" onclick="handleClick(this.val);"><span>Warm</span>
   <input type="radio" name="sta_choice" id="o3" value="Active" onclick="handleClick(this.val);"><span>Active</span>
   <input type="radio" name="sta_choice" value="All" checked><span>All</span>

  <div class="ref">
  </div>
```

**SQL**

```
  $sql="select * from client where active=0 and comp_id='$comp' order by c_name asc limit $i,5";
```

My problem is I want to pass the value of radio button to the query dynamically
and  reload the ref div

[image]
If I selected cold I shows only cold value.

Comment: Is there any form present?

Comment: you need to use check box in place of radio button to implement check all functionality. Second thing you have not used "sta_choice" in your query. You need to clarify your quesiton

Comment: @ManishShukla Why? You can use radioboxes as well if you just want one option to be selected. That works exactly like checkboxes.

Comment: What is `handleClick()`?  Does this send off to your PHP script?  I personally think you should use an event handler, rather than an onclick attribute.

Comment: do you already have the connection to database, please provide more info

Comment: I used form tag..please see my update..

Comment: First of all you given HTML is not correct. Lots of closing tags missing. Second As pe my understanding you should use ajax to update div content on selection of radio button without refreshing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use jQuery for something like this.

Get the value (the only unique "identifier" available in the code you have provided) of the radio option and send that value via AJAX to a script to be included as a parameter in your query. Finally, output the result of the query in your "ref" div

```
<script>
$(':radio').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);

    alert(this.value); // for testing

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processor.php",
        cache: false,

        data: { action: this.value },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        success: function(text) {
            alert(text);  // for testing
            $(".ref").html("<p>" + text + "</p>");          
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
echo 'You sent me '.$_POST['action'];
?>
```

Comment: how to pass two value in action.  I want to pass $comp value along this.value.$sql="select * from client where active=0 and comp_id='$comp' order by c_name asc limit $i,5";

Comment: You just add key-value pairs to the data parameter:
data: { action: this.value, comp: compvalue },

Answer (score 0):

use `$comp=$_REQUEST['<radio_name>']` i.e. in your case `$comp=$_REQUEST['sta_choice'];` and then pass it in your query which will dynamically fetch data as per your requirement but in case of single condition or single value dependency the radio button works fine but if you want to fetch data depending on multiple value then you should use check boxes with array data type and user `WHERE IN ()` function in your query or as suitable depending on your requirement.

Hope this will  help you in solving your problem

Comment: I want to refresh the div tag once I click radio button.

Comment: if you are posting the value from a form using php POST then the div will automatically get refreshed and if you are submitting the form usiong Ajax then after ther completion of the ajax just add ` $('#div1-wrapper').load(url + ' #div1'); `